# How to put \' in my string using paste0 function

Tags: r, string, paste

I have an array:

```
t <- c("IMCR01","IMFA02","IMFA03")
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
"\'IMCR01\'","\'IMFA02\'","\'IMFA03\'"
```

I tried different ways like:

```
paste0("\'",t,"\'")
paste0("\\'",t,"\\'")
paste0("\\\\'",t,"\\\\'")
```

But none of them is correct. Any other functions are OK as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your second attempt is correct:

```
paste0("\\'",t,"\\'")
```

If you want to tell `paste` to use a literal backslash, you need to escape it once (but not twice, as you would need within a regex pattern).  This would output the following to the console in R:

```
[1] "\\'IMCR01\\'" "\\'IMFA02\\'" "\\'IMFA03\\'"
```

The trick here is that the backslash is even being escaped by R in the console output.  If you were instead to write `t` to a text file, you would only see a single backslash as you wanted:

```
write(t, file = "/path/to/your/file.txt")
```

But why does R need to escape backslash when writing to its own console?  One possibility is that if it were to write a literal `\n` then this would actually be interpreted by the console as a newline.  Hence the need for eacaping is still there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never noticed such detail!

Comment: @FengChen -  `cat` is your friend when checking what strings "actually" are: `cat(paste0("\\'",t,"\\'"), "\n")` for instance.